# Could someone explain me this block of code line by line? Jquery - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, post

I've just started to learn jquery&javascript, and in my project I've found this block of code, and I'm wondering what does it mean, some parts are confusing to me, all I've understand so far is that this is triggering on some control change event but how can I know which control and how does this work in fact?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#MainGroupID").change(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var subItems="";
            $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetSubgroupByMainGroup", "Article")", {id:val} ,function (data) {
              $.each(data,function(index,item){
                subItems+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>"
              });
              $("#SubGroupID").html(subItems)
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please some explanation line by line I'm trying to understand this stuffs how do they work with code behind etc etc :/

Maybe it's stupid question but .. :/

Thanks guys,
Cheers!

Comment: Go to the [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com/) docs and look up each of the methods yourself. There are detailed explanations and examples for each.  Please also read [What not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 2):

```
//$(function () {
```

this part is used to invoke the function when the DOM is ready.

```
$("#MainGroupID").change
```

//is a change event - like the value of the input has changed.

```
var val = $(this).val();
```

//You are picking up the value of the input

```
var subItems="";
```

// you are creating a placeholder variable to hold data

```
$.getJSON(
```

//this is a call to get json data.

```
$.each
```

//you are now looping through the data obtained from the json call

```
subItems+="<option value='"+item.Value+"'>"+item.Text+"</option>"
```

//you are now populating the variable you had set

```
$("#SubGroupID").html(subItems)
```

//this places the content of the obtained data and the structure from the placeholder into the div with the id SubGroupID

Comment: Rox -- to help you out to understand or see what's going on -- use console.log("value", value) --- if you are using chrome for example f12 -- you can see what the values are -- it may help debug